# How to use Master interface in ibe package in golang

Tags: go, package

I'm trying to generate private key using the Extract() in the Master interface of the ibe package, here's the link of the package,"https://godoc.org/v.io/x/lib/ibe#Master". In the package, the input of Extract is id, and consist of {0,1}*, so I convert Mac id to binary string first, and then use the binary string to generate correspond private key. 
My code is like this.

```
package main
import (
"fmt"
"v.io/x/lib/ibe"
)

var Macid = "00055DNEFF"
var id string
var PrivateKey string

func stringToBin(Macid string) (id string) {
    for _, c := range Macid {
        id = fmt.Sprintf("%s%b", id, c)
    }
    return
}
type Master string
func (master Master) Extract(id string) (PrivateKey, error) {
    return PrivateKey
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println("MacID is " + Macid + ", public key is" + stringToBin(Macid) + ", private key is" + ibe.Extract(id))

}
```

But I always got errors

> $ go build pkg.go
>
> command-line-arguments
>
> ./pkg.go:27: PrivateKey is not a type
>
> ./pkg.go:33: undefined: ibe in ibe.Extract

I'm all new to go, and I have read the tour of go, but I couldn't get it.
Can anyone help me with this? Thank you.

Comment: Here's the interface I'm trying to use in ibe._// Master is the interface used to extract private keys for arbitrary identities._
    'type Master interface {
     Extract(id string) (PrivateKey, error)
     Params() Params
    }'

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 implementations of Master provided in the ibe package (bb1 and bb2).
These can be accessed using either ibe.SetupBB1() or ibe.SetupBB2()

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "log"

    "v.io/x/lib/ibe"
)

var Macid = "00055DNEFF"

func stringToBin(Macid string) (id string) {
    for _, c := range Macid {
        id = fmt.Sprintf("%s%b", id, c)
    }
    return
}

func main() {
    bb2Master, err := ibe.SetupBB2()
    // or
    // bb1Master, err := ibe.SetupBB1()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    id := stringToBin(Macid)
    privateKey, err := bb2Master.Extract(id)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    fmt.Printf("MacID is %v, private key is %v", Macid, privateKey)

    // etc...
    // privateKey.Decrypt(C, m)
}
```

Comment: Yes, thank you for your answer, I figured that out. But I found that, the private keys I extracted each time are not the same. That is frustrating...I looked into that and found several random() in the Setup()s and Extract()s. I'm now reading the paper( http://crypto.stanford.edu/~dabo/papers/bfibe.pdf ) trying to find out that how the keys like that can even working...

Comment: Hi Joshua, I try to follow your code to print the ciphertext and decrypted text using the functions, but I always can't get them. I checked the original ibe library and I think it just can't print those two texts, right?

Answer (score 0):

@Joshua Wales

```
package main

import (
"fmt"

"log"

"v.io/x/lib/ibe"
)

var Macid = "00055DNEFF"

func stringToBin(Macid string) (id string) {
for _, c := range Macid {
    id = fmt.Sprintf("%s%b", id, c)
}
return
}

func main() {
bb1Master, err := ibe.SetupBB1()

if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

id := stringToBin(Macid)
privateKey, err := bb1Master.Extract(id)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

fmt.Printf("MacID is %v, private key is %v", Macid, privateKey)

m := []byte("HelloAuthentication")
overhead := bb1Master.Params().CiphertextOverhead()
C := make([]byte, len(m)+overhead)

if err := bb1Master.Params().Encrypt(Macid, m, C); err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

fmt.Printf("Ciphertext is : ", bb1Master.Params().Encrypt(Macid, m, C))

if err := privateKey.Decrypt(C, m); err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

fmt.Printf("Decrypted text is : ", privateKey.Decrypt(C, m))


}
```

@